# How can I get this little javascript countdown timer to work?

Tags: javascript

I found the below script somewhere, but it is failing. I have set some alerts to see where it stops. Alert #1 is popping up, but alert #2 is not. That tells me that something is wrong with either `getTime()` or `setHours()`.

The script is invoked in the body-tag: `onload="javascript: countdown();"`.

```
function countdown() {
    alert("1");
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date().getTime();
    countDownDate.setHours(countDownDate.getHours() + 2);
    alert("2");

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function () {
        // Get today's date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        //var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        //var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("SessionCookieExpirationCountdown").innerHTML = "Logging out in " + minutes + ":" + seconds|
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        // If the count down is finished, write some text
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("SessionCookieExpirationCountdown").innerHTML = "Logged out";
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: What errors (if any) are display in your browser console?

Comment: @empiric `Uncaught TypeError: countDownDate.getHours is not a function`.

Comment: Now you know whats wrong. `getHours` can only be invoked on an instance of `new Date` but you are calling it on the return value of `getTime()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `new Date().getTime()` you could use `Date.now()` to get timestamp. To add 2 hour delay I used `Date.now() + 2 hours in ms (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` instead of using `setHours`.

The problem in your code is in that part:

```js
var countDownDate = new Date().getTime();
countDownDate.setHours(countDownDate.getHours() + 2);
```

You are trying to call `new Date.getTime().setHours()` but getTime() returns number which has not `setHours` method.

Now everything works fine.

```js
function countdown() {
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  // 60000 (1 second in ms) * 60 (1 minute in seconds)
  var countDownDate = Date.now() + 60000 * 60;

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = Date.now();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("SessionCookieExpirationCountdown").innerHTML = "Logging out in " + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("SessionCookieExpirationCountdown").innerHTML = "Logged out";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="countdown()">
  <div id="SessionCookieExpirationCountdown"></div>
</body>
```