# Countdown timer reset when mousemove or keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help resetting the timer to its start time when `mousemove` or `keypress`.

Found this script on this link [How can I get this little javascript countdown timer to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818028/how-can-i-get-this-little-javascript-countdown-timer-to-work)

What I've done so far is add reset timer function for `mousemove` and `keypress` it does reset the timer but the alert popups multiple times when I did `keypress` or `mousemove`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).mousemove(resetTimer);
    $(this).keypress(resetTimer);
});

function resetTimer() { 
    clearInterval(x);
    countdown();
}

function countdown() {
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  // 60000 (1 second in ms) * 60 (1 minute in seconds)
  var countDownDate = Date.now() + 10000 * 60;

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = Date.now();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("SessionCookieExpirationCountdown").innerHTML = "Logging out in " + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("SessionCookieExpirationCountdown").innerHTML = "Countdown End";
       timeup();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

function timeup() {
    alert('times up');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="countdown()">
  <div id="SessionCookieExpirationCountdown"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear interval before starting a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76685621/383904) and many many other similar questions

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `x` is inside the `countdown()` method and you were trying to access it in the `resetTimer()` method.  It can't see into the variables in there.

The fix is to just move that viable up a level so that both methods can share it.  I've renamed `x` to `timer` to make it easier to understand too.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).mousemove(resetTimer);
    $(this).keypress(resetTimer);
});

var timer = null;

function resetTimer() { 
    clearInterval(timer);
    countdown();
}

function countdown() {
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  // 60000 (1 second in ms) * 60 (1 minute in seconds)
  var countDownDate = Date.now() + 10000 * 60;

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = Date.now();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("SessionCookieExpirationCountdown").innerHTML = "Logging out in " + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById("SessionCookieExpirationCountdown").innerHTML = "Countdown End";
       timeup();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

function timeup() {
    alert('times up');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="countdown()">
  <div id="SessionCookieExpirationCountdown"></div>
</body>
```